# XSL analyze string alternative for XSL 1.0

Tags: xml, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

Is there a way to perform the analyze string operation in XSL 1.0
For example in XSL 2.0 we can have:

```
  <xsl:analyze-string select="Description" regex="$param1">
    <xsl:matching-substring>
    <span style="background-color: papayawhip;">
<xsl:value-of select="."/></span>
    </xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:non-matching-substring>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:non-matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
```

So this will look for param1 in the Description node and replace it with a `<span>`. Is it possible to do something like this with XSL 1.0?

Comment: How does `$param` look, do you really need regular expression support? Or are you simply looking for string constants you want to wrap?

Comment: It is just a string constant. So basically it is just a search keyword, if that is present anywhere in the description node, I want to highlight it using the span.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to look for substrings in the `Description` element then that is possible with XSLT 1.0 by writing a named, recursive template:

```
<xsl:stylesheet 
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:param name="param1" select="'foo'"/>

<xsl:template name="wrap">
  <xsl:param name="input"/>
  <xsl:param name="search"/>
  <xsl:param name="wrapper-element" select="'span'"/>
  <xsl:param name="wrapper-style" select="'background-color: papayawhip;'"/>
  <xsl:choose>
     <xsl:when test="not(contains($input, $search))">
       <xsl:value-of select="$input"/>
     </xsl:when>
     <xsl:otherwise>
       <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($input, $search)"/>
       <xsl:element name="{$wrapper-element}">
         <xsl:if test="$wrapper-style">
           <xsl:attribute name="style">
             <xsl:value-of select="$wrapper-style"/>
           </xsl:attribute>
         </xsl:if>
         <xsl:value-of select="$search"/>
       </xsl:element>
       <xsl:call-template name="wrap">
         <xsl:with-param name="input" select="substring-after($input, $search)"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="search" select="$search"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="wrapper-element" select="$wrapper-element"/>
         <xsl:with-param name="wrapper-style" select="$wrapper-style"/>
       </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Description">
  <div>
    <xsl:call-template name="wrap">
      <xsl:with-param name="input" select="."/>
      <xsl:with-param name="search" select="$param1"/>
    </xsl:call-template>
  </div>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Such code then transforms

```
<Root>
  <Description>foo bar baz foobar test whatever foo</Description>
</Root>
```

into

```
  <div><span style="background-color: papayawhip;">foo</span> bar baz <span style="background-color: papayawhip;">foo</span>bar test whatever <span style="background-color: papayawhip;">foo</span></div>
```

Take that as an example you can adapt to suit your needs somehow, it is certainly not meant as a full replacement of XSLT 2.0's analyze-string.

Answer (score 3):

Use something like:

```
<xsl:if test="contains(x, $param)">
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-before(x, $param)"/>
  <span><xsl:value-of select="$param"/></span>
  <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(x, $param)"/>
</xsl:if>
```